# use mysql_num_rows for two tables

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

I have a problem with mysql duplication. I have two tables name as student and temp_student. Both tables have same fields except for temp_student, i've add studentStatus and statusNote. The problem is, when I use `mysql_num_rows` for any tables to search the duplication data, such as student name, it echos the duplication error. But when i use `mysql_num_rows` for both tables, and i inserted the same student name into both table, the data still duplicate. Here is my code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$checkName = mysql_query("select *from student where name = '$name'");
$checkNameTemp = mysql_query("select * from temp_student where name = '$name");

//$check = $checkName + $checkNameTemp;

if(mysql_num_rows($checkName) && mysql_num_rows($checkNameTemp)  > 0){
echo "Duplicate Data";
}
else{

$insertStudentQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO student(name,noic, createDate) VALUES('$name','$Ic', NOW())");

$insertStudentQueryTemporary = mysql_query("INSERT INTO temp_student(name,noic, createDate) VALUES('$name','$Ic', NOW())");

}
```

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*()` family of functions. They're deprecated. Check out MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Us join instead of two queries

Comment: You need to join the student table to the temp_student table, then use select count(id) would be more efficient than select *, as you only want a count, so no point returning all data.

Answer (score 0):

Your IF will only hit when both have more than 0 rows. Not if any has. Use || to check for any non zero rows.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($checkName) || mysql_num_rows($checkNameTemp)){
    echo "Duplicate Data";
}
```

Comment: oh my goodness.. thanks for helping.. i almost forget of 'OR' operator.. i forget that i want to send the duplicate data either student or temp_student table..

Comment: You might also want to checkout the `SELECT UNION` sql statement to make only one query.

Comment: I think a UNION of two SELECTS should have it's combined total in mysql_num_rows, but you will have to verify that.

Comment: oooo.. okay.. i will try learn and use the MySQL UNION for my next projects.. by the way thanks for help me out..